Collect the same data for the same point more than once in AGOL
My team goes into the field and checks the same point features (i.e. manholes) multiple times a year. Is there a way to collect the same data each time we visit a manhole on different days?
We don't want to edit and overwrite any of the previous visit's work. We just want to record another day's worth of the same data.
Additionally, assuming this was possible to collect the same data for the same point more than once, how would that export look?

yes using Date fields and the Field App with ArcGIS Online https://doc.arcgis.com/en/arcgis-online/manage-data/work-with-date-fields.htm https://www.esri.com/en-us/arcgis/products/arcgis-field-maps/overview

@TomazicM I apologize for not completely understanding. We are new to field collection. We use the Date and Time fields when we go out, but there is just the option to enter in everything once, whereas we will go multiple times to the same point. How do we have a new form for each visit that all gets tied to the same point? Thanks so much for your help!

This data should be collected for an 'Inspection' object (or similar), not for a manhole object.  The inspection can then be joined/related to the manhole.  Ie, each manhole object can be related to multiple Inspection objects.  You can collect this related Inspection data in either Field Maps or in Survey123, but there is some initial setup required to make it work nicely.

@SonofaBeach thanks for the clarification. I need to revisit my data and produce a new blank layer to hold the inspection items.

I would not create a layer for the inspection items, but just a table.  Ie, a non-spatial table.  The related manhole has the location for each of its inspections.  You can create a 'Relate' between the manhole feature class and the inspections table.  This will make it easy to create a related inspection from a manhole feature (eg, in Field Maps).  Post a new question here if further information is required.
